# Unbox + Realm native "List" object

Tags: ios, swift, realm, unbox

**Update**

> Finally author of the `Unbox` library answer my question.
>   https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox/issues/156

---

I'm trying to use `Unbox` to make `Realm` object with other related objects inside using `List`. The `JSON` response from server has this structure.

```
[
  {
    "name": "bla bla",
    "desc": "bla bla",
    "sequential": true,
    "createdAt": "2017-01-23T09:58:05.095Z",
    "hmImages": [
      {
        "urlBase": "https://blabla.com",
        "fullresPath": "/blaPath/iyba783fR81L8y.jpg",
        "id": "bla bla"
      },
      {
        "urlBase": "https://blabla.com",
        "fullresPath": "/blaPath/iyba783fR81L8y.jpg",
        "id": "bla bla"
      }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "id": "bla bla"
  },
  {
    "name": "bla bla",
    "desc": "bla bla",
    "sequential": true,
    "createdAt": "2017-01-23T09:58:05.095Z",
    "hmImages": [
      {
        "urlBase": "https://blabla.com",
        "fullresPath": "/blaPath/iyba783fR81L8y.jpg",
        "id": "bla bla"
      }
    ]
    "tags": [],
    "id": "bla bla"
  }
]
```

Note that root object is an `Array` of dictionaries. Every dictionary has an `Array` of image dictionaries.

The class to save objects in `Realm` looks like this:

```
// MARK: - Realm
final class Challenge: Object {

    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var desc = ""
    dynamic var sequential = false
    dynamic var createdAt = Date()
    dynamic var btPlayground = ""

    // Relations
    let hmImages = List<Image>()
    let tags = List<Tag>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}

// MARK: - Unboxable
extension Challenge: Unboxable {

    convenience init(unboxer: Unboxer) throws {
        self.init()

        // Date formatter
        let dateFormatter = ISODateFormatter()

        id = try unboxer.unbox(key: "id")
        name = try unboxer.unbox(key: "name")
        desc = try unboxer.unbox(key: "desc")
        sequential = try unboxer.unbox(key: "sequential")
        createdAt = try unboxer.unbox(key: "createdAt", formatter: dateFormatter)
        btPlayground = try unboxer.unbox(key: "btPlayground")

    }

}
```

The problem occurs with `hmImages` keypath. `Unbox` can't parse automatically and I need a way to do this.

I tried `UnboxableByTransform` with something like this:

```
extension List<T>: UnboxableByTransform {

    public typealias UnboxRawValue = [[String:Any]]

    public static func transform(unboxedValue: Array<[UnboxableDictionary]>) -> List<T>? {


    }

}
```

but didn't work.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You just do it in a wrong way. For json, read [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#json).

If you insist your own way. You should consider of that Realm doesn't accept `Any` type as you used in `public typealias UnboxRawValue = [[String:Any]]`, you can only use the types that Realm lists. That are Bool, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Double, Float, String, NSDate, and NSData.